# OPC connection active but LabView does not see variable changes

Tags: labview, opc, codesys

I have OPC server on CodeSys. I am trying to read variables using LabView.

I have tried two options:

- using DataBinding to OPC Variables in controls
- using DataSocket Open, Read, Write, Close VI

LabView returns no error. When I use data binding control it is green and the message is "Active: Connected to OPC server".

[image]

Unfortunately when I force variables in CodeSys i see no changes in LabView.

Comment: Hello, which API do you use in LabVIEW. Do you use NI DSC or OPC DA client API for LabVIEW?

Comment: NI Data Socket mechanism

Comment: Also, you can use this one, for faster OPC and big amounts of tags: http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/216309

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. Poor diagnostics of LabView Data Socket mechanism was really confusing in this case. The icon shown that variable is "Active: Connected to OPC Server" while it was not.

I have used Server Explorer from http://www.opcconnect.com/freecli.php and then reconfigured everything in CodeSys OPC Server configuration and firewall.